# Want to update the list in every entry view?

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

> i'am having a list with textview, many data's are flowing in list and having one textview in xml....problem is i want to update the every textview entry in the list..i want to update the (TAG_QTY) textview in list when every value entry...

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { TAG_BARCODE, TAG_DIVISION, TAG_MRP,TAG_QTY}, new int[] {
                    R.id.txt, R.id.txt1, R.id.mrp,R.id.qty1 });
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    // selecting single ListView item
    ListView lv = getListView();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            //String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.qty1)).getText().toString();
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null);
            //final View textEntryView;

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    context);

            // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
            alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);
            fourth = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.qty1);
            userInput = (EditText)promptsView.findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);
            //String ed = userInput.getText().toString();
          //final int ed= Integer.parseInt(userInput.getText().toString());
            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                    String ed = userInput.getText().toString().trim();
                                    fourth.setText(ed);
                             }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();

        }
    }
    );
```

Comment: your question is unclear. Do you want to refresh the list after each new entry?

Comment: no...if i click one view in the list want to edit the textview which is in list..

Comment: take the id of the list view child of whom text view you want to edit, then in that view change find the id of your textview field and set the new text on that.

Comment: i'dont no how to add child in list...pls give some example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the list view child

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        View c = lv.getChildAt(position);
        // c is your list view child which is clicked
        final TextView tv = (TextView) c.findViewById(R.id.qty1);
        // tv is your textview of whom vwlue you have to change.
        //changes the value of textview here and den notify data set changed and refresh the list.         
       }
     });
```